# boost.asio : multi ports application-layer protocol

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

I am designing a client-server app and I need to use three different channels between them.
Below on the schema, the client opens a connection to the server (1), and then the server opens two connections to the client on other ports (2).

```
|-----------|                  |-----------|
|           |  (1) port: 8000  |           |
|           |<-----------------|           |
|           |                  |           |
|           |                  |           |
|  Server   |  (2) port: 8001  |  Client   |
|           |----------------->|           |
|           |                  |           |
|           |  (2) port: 8002  |           |
|           |----------------->|           |
|-----------|                  |-----------|
```

A simple channel server example :http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

My questions is how to implement this, based on boost.asio framework ? Or, how to open the new connections (2) from the server ?

P.S. Maybe a better protocol could be to open the two other connections from client when the first is established ? But what could be the structure used in asio in this case ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: Things will get tricky if client and server are across a NAT, because you might not be able to open connection from server to client on a new port.

Comment: Really good comment ! So I can forget my first idea. Maybe you have an other idea for me ? :) A token based system returned by the server to the client which can use it to open the new streams ?

Comment: Shame I didn't watch the comments. I was gonna say the same, but have also taken the finger-exercise to come up with a demo implementation of the picture shown. Posting anyways

Comment: You could in theory also multiplex the data streams on top of a single connection. It all depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, any system that's required to be robust should not assume that routing/firewalling is such that connections can be made back to the client from the server.

How would we go around this?

- client connects to server:8000
- server responds with a session UID
- client is responsible for connecting two more "channels", using the session UID as a correlation ID
- server decides that a session is completely ready if all 3 "channels" (i.e. sockets) participating in with a given session UID have been connected. If there's a timeout for this to happen, the server jots the whole session and closes any sockets that had been opened.

This is fairly easy, but requires a wire protocol to coordinate the sessions and channel "roles" for connections. I did initially elect not to implement this as a demo. Instead I thought it would be a nice exercise to learn Boost Asio, and implemented the back-channels (initiated from the server side) as in your original drawing.

The full code is on github: https://gist.github.com/sehe/9946161

Notes:

- there is a 'general' listener implementation that is used for both the server (port 8000) and "back-channels" (ports 8001,8002). See [listener.hpp](https://gist.github.com/sehe/9946161#file-listener-hpp)
- I opted for the *stackless coroutine* approach. This requires Boost Asio 1.54
- This approach has led to relative abuse of `shared_ptr<>`, at least in my view. The reason is that it's very beneficial if the coroutine (which is also the completion functor) is copyable without any issues. I could probably clean this up by making the class itself `enable_shared_from_this` and bind to `shared_from_this` instead. The benefit now is that there are (almost) no `bind`-expressions.
- Creating the 'back channels' is done in the server class [which *overrides* `on_accept`](https://gist.github.com/sehe/9946161#file-server-hpp-L34):

  ```
  virtual bool on_accept(tcp::socket& socket) override
  {
      auto host = socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
      // for now setting up the back-connections is all synchronous -
      // that might not work well in practice (scaling, latency) but...
      try
      {
          tcp::resolver resolver(socket.get_io_service());
          auto ep1 = resolver.resolve(tcp::resolver::query(host, "8001"));
          auto ep2 = resolver.resolve(tcp::resolver::query(host, "8002"));

          backsock1 = make_shared<tcp::socket>(socket.get_io_service());
          backsock2 = make_shared<tcp::socket>(socket.get_io_service());

          backsock1->connect(*ep1);
          backsock2->connect(*ep2);

          std::cerr << "on_accept: back channels connected for " << host << "\n";
      } catch(std::exception const& e)
      {
          std::cerr << "on_accept: '" << e.what() << "' for " << host << "\n";
          return false;
      }

      return base_type::on_accept(socket);
  }
  ```
- If `on_accept` fails (e.g. for our server cannot connect the back-channels) an error is returned on the "main" socket (initial connection) and the session is aborted

There are three programs:

- [`run_server`](https://gist.github.com/sehe/9946161#file-run_server-cpp) (which listens on port 8000)
- [`run_client`](https://gist.github.com/sehe/9946161#file-run_client-cpp) (which connects to port 8000 and listens on 8001,8002), and sends 1 message. You can observe how the the server responds by connecting on the back-channels and sending different messages on all three sockets.
- [`test`](https://gist.github.com/sehe/9946161#file-test-cpp) (which combines the two):

  ```
  #include <boost/asio.hpp>
  #include <boost/thread.hpp>
  #include "server.hpp"
  #include "client.hpp"

  int main()
  {
      boost::asio::io_service svc;

      // start service on a separate thread
      boost::thread th([&svc] { 
              svc.post(demo::server(svc));
              svc.run(); 
              });

      boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(500)); // allow server to start accepting

      // post client traffic to the service
      std::cerr << "Starting a test client that sends a message...\n";
      demo::client client(svc, "localhost", "8000");

      // await interrupt (or new connections)
      th.join();
  }
  ```

The output of the last program looks like:

```
Starting a test client that sends a message...
on_accept: back channels connected for 127.0.0.1
listener 127.0.0.1:8000: accepting connection from 127.0.0.1:40999
listener 127.0.0.1:8000: 'hello world from demo client' received from 127.0.0.1:40999
listener 127.0.0.1:8001: accepting connection from 127.0.0.1:40132
listener 127.0.0.1:8002: accepting connection from 127.0.0.1:37970
listener 127.0.0.1:8001: 'We've received a request of length 29' received from 127.0.0.1:40132
listener 127.0.0.1:8002: 'We're handling it in void demo::server::do_back_chatter(const string&)' received from 127.0.0.1:37970
listener 127.0.0.1:40999: 'ECHO hello world from demo client' received from 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !! But as said above, this won't work behind a router with NAT :/ 
I will try to implement the application-layer protocol you describe first.